# Swagger behind Nginx reverse proxy cannot retrieve v3/api-docs

Tags: nginx, swagger, swagger-ui, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having problem setting up an java API documented with swagger-ui behind a NGINX reverse proxy.

The whole application is deployed in a OpenShift cluster. Nginx is setup without https but the route on the cluster is setup to provide an https endpoint.

**My reverse proxy setup:**

*nginx.conf*

```
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include       /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    include       /etc/nginx/resolvers.conf;

    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    include       /etc/nginx/http.server.conf;
}
```

*http.server.conf*

```
    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /nginx_status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log off;
        }


        include       /etc/nginx/apiproxies.conf;

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
```

*apiproxies.conf*

```
location /v3 {
  set $upstream http://service-name.service-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8080;
  proxy_pass $upstream;
}
location /swagger-ui {
      set $upstream http://service-name.service-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8080;
      proxy_pass $upstream;
}
```

*proxy.conf*

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
# proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
# proxy_set_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
```

**The problem:**

When I try to load the application from the browser the UI loads but i get the error that it was not possible to retrieve /v3/api-docs .

[image]

the error message in the console is:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://domain.example:8080/v3/api-docs/”
```

It tries to retrieve http data from https page and the get is blocked.

That's not it, the url has this port (:8080) indication that shouldn't be there.

Can someone please direct me in troubleshooting this issue? Please let me know if the information i provided is not sufficient

**UPDATE:**

if request:
`https://domain.example/v3/api-docs` i get redirected (301 Moved Permanently) to `https://domain.example:8080/v3/api-docs/`

Comment: in both virtual host locations, you are proxy pass to `http://service-name.service-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8080` which is the same for both. Anything that you di not show us?

Comment: @GeorgiStefkoff I have also some static content on the web server. I wanted to do the reverse_proxying only for these two paths. Is it a misconfiguration?

Comment: first, you have to be sure that your application is exposing endpoint `api-docs` at port `8080`. Also, provide the entire nginx configuration (mocked)

Comment: @GeorgiStefkoff I am sure about the port.  I just added my complete configuration